# Why is there a parallel resistor on this regulator ouput?

Tags: voltage-regulator, filter

In the regulator circuit below
[image]

What is the reason for having the R103 470Ω on the output of the regulator?
I feel this is wasting 9mA of current.
Could it be for adjusting the properties of the filter made in pair with the capacitor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *What is the reason for having the R103 470Ω on the output of the
> regulator? I feel this is wasting 9mA of current.*

Look at the bottom of page 25 in the [data sheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC2915x-30x-50x-75x-High-Current-Low-Dropout-Regulators-DS20005685B.pdf): -

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Then in that case we can achieve the same result by choosing R101=330Ω and R102=140Ω. Not sure on the reason for opting for the 3 resistors solution here. (I took the diagram from the sim800c datasheet).

Comment: @user290017 maybe; maybe not - the data sheet will recommend resistor values to use for the feedback and, if the values are too low, you might not get the correct regulation dynamic response to varying load currents.

Comment: I did think about that but on page 3 there is an application example using 191Ω and 187Ω in feedback resistors. These are clearly in the same order of magnitude.

Comment: That's for the MIC29152 but maybe it's good for all of the adjustable types listed. Make sure that the data sheet I've linked is for your device. Originally, I linked to the MIC29302A device but then I realized you didn't put an "A" on the end so double check.

Comment: @user290017 Section 4.4 of the data sheet explicitly says you can scale the feedback resistors to draw the minimum load current if necessary. Of course if the real load always draws a sufficiently high current, there is no reason to waste another 9ma and R103 (and/or low values of R101/R102) are not required.

Comment: Thank you for the great input both of you.